# Make content of absolute div scrollable

Tags: html, css, cordova

Hi I have a cordova app and I need to build a chat.

http://jsfiddle.net/jGLvk/1355/

I put the divs with position absolute to when the keyboard on the phone appears all the content move to up too.

So, when I did that the content doesn't show the scroll. How Can I resolve this?

```
<div class="page-content messages-content" style="position:absolute; width:100%; bottom:48px; top:auto;">
        <div class="messages" style="position:absolute; width:100%; bottom:10px; top:auto; overflow-y:auto;">
```

Pay attention on this lines, where all the new messages will 
be inserted.

Thanks.

Comment: you need to add the overflow scroll to parent, so move it to the upper div

Comment: I have tried to add the the attribute overflow with auto, scroll and visible on all the parents tags.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it with overriding inline styles. Not sure if you should use it (I'm actually sure that you shouldn't)

```
.messages-auto-layout {
  position: static !important;
}
```

I'm not sure if this is helpful because those styles are most probably applied via JS so there must be a way how to solve it in a more smarter way. Maybe stripping off all JS styles and use only css? I have never build an App using Cordova so I might be missing some context here.

Here is the link --> http://jsfiddle.net/9rsgdrw5/1/